# How Can I use this code to directly change my image more than one time by using after command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, canvas

I really not sure where i do blunders but I try it many time but not get result, actually I wanted to change my image in tkinter window after sometime without creating a button, I find some code from here and do changes on it but I am not able to change image after once, the image is change only once, after second image is static and not change in visible, please help to find a solution.

```
val = 2000 #milisecond
val1 = 1000 #milisecond
val2 = 5000 #milisecond

from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class myGUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=800, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        filename="image1.png"
        image = Image.open(filename)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.img = self.canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=self.photo)


        self.root.after(val, self.change_photo)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def change_photo(self):
        filename = "image2.png"
        image = Image.open(filename)

        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.img, image=self.photo)

        # From Here I will not achieve my goal

        def __init__(self):

            self.root.after(val1, self.change_photo1)


        def change_photo1(self):
            filename = "image1.png"
            image = Image.open(filename)

            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.img, image=self.photo)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui = myGUI()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.after()` inside `change_photo()` function.  As you want to cycle the images, suggest to use `itertools.cycle()` as below:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
from itertools import cycle

class myGUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=800, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.val = 1000

        filenames = ("image1.png", "image2.png")
        self.images = cycle(filenames)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=next(self.images))
        self.img = self.canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=self.photo)

        self.root.after(self.val, self.change_photo)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def change_photo(self):
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=next(self.images))
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.img, image=self.photo)
        self.root.after(self.val, self.change_photo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui = myGUI()
```

---

Example without using `cycle`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

class myGUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=800, bg='orange')
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.val = 1000

        self.images = ("image1.png", "image2.png")
        self.img = self.canvas.create_image(250, 250)

        self.change_photo()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def change_photo(self, index=0):
        if index < len(self.images):
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=self.images[index])
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.img, image=self.photo)
            self.root.after(self.val, self.change_photo, index+1)
        else:
            print("No more image")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui = myGUI()
```

Comment: Oh great but I don.t want to cycle it, only wanted that my image is open as #tkinter window open, after sometime second image image show than third image show and so on. not want to cycle the image, with after command the whole scenario done. Remember without any button

Comment: @AwaisBinRiaz Answer updated with example not using `cycle()`.

Comment: Thanks, not get proper but the from this example I do that.